# \displaystyle and \limit commands don't seem to work when rendering to mathml

Tags: pandoc, htlatex, displaystyle, mathml

I am trying to render a latex file to mathml for viewing in firefox. However, when trying to render the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\(\displaystyle\sum\limits_i\)
\end{document}
```

to mathml, neither `pandoc` nor `ht4tex` render the `i` correctly, under the sigma sign. I have tried the following commands:

```
pandoc text.tex --mathml
```

and

```
htlatex test.tex "html,mathml"
```

but neither produce the desired output.

Note that when I compile to a pdf file using `pdflatex` or when using pandoc with the `--mathjax` option the file renders correctly, but I'm trying to get a solution that produces only mathml.

Comment: you could raise that with the tex4ht developers, but why would you need such a construct rather than simply `\[\sum_i\]` you should almost never need `\displaystyle` or `\limits` within a document, just in defining commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is hard to support switching commands such as `\itshape`, `\large` or `\displaystyle` in `tex4ht`. `tex4ht` just cannot know where it should close the affected content in a reliable way. The font switches are supported using the font information in the DVI file, but there is no such information for `\displaystyle`.

It is much better to use commands that clearly mark the affected text, like `\textit` for example. For your use, you need to define a custom command that can be then patched by `tex4ht` to insert correct MathML elements.

I would redefine your TeX file in the following way, introducing the `\displaycontent` command:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/494579/2891
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\displaycontent[1]{\displaystyle#1}
\begin{document}
\(\displaycontent{\sum\limits_i}\)
\end{document}
```

The configuration for `tex4ht`, `myconfig.cfg` may look as follows:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\renewcommand\displaycontent[1]{\HCode{<mstyle displaystyle="true">}#1\HCode{</mstyle>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It just redefines the `\displaycontent` to include `<mstyle displaystyle="true">` before and `</mstyle>` after the enclosed content.

The file can be compiled using

```
make4ht -c myconfig.cfg test.tex
```

This is the resulting MathML:

```xml
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML' display='inline'><mrow><mstyle displaystyle='true'><munder class='msub'><mrow><mo class='MathClass-op'>∑</mo>
  </mrow><mrow><mi>i</mi></mrow></munder></mstyle></mrow></math>
```

And it is how it is rendered by Firefox:

[image]